# Accesing dictionary from another script on Roblox developper

Tags: lua, roblox, lua-table

I'm new on Roblox developping and Lua and I'm stuck on a very basic issue, I've created a module script that returns a dictionary with some values... I need that dictionary on another script... but how?

Here's my code (script is in ReplicatedStorage) :

```
local ConfigLevelsModule = {
    {
        key = "book",
        preu = "3"
    },
    {
        key = "video",
        preu = "2"
    }
}

return ConfigLevelsModule
```

then on another script (is on Workspace) I do:

```
local ConfigLevelsModule = require(game.ReplicatedStorage.ConfigLevelsModule)
```

but give me this error

```
  19:30:54.940  Attempted to call require with invalid argument(s).  -  Servidor - Script:2
```

How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This error shows up when you call `require` with something that isn't a [ModuleScript](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ModuleScript).

Double check that `game.ReplicatedStorage.ConfigLevelsModule` is actually a ModuleScript and not a regular [Script](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Script) or [LocalScript](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/LocalScript).

Comment: I posted on my original post the script I'm using... is that a ModuleScript? If not what do I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: You did say you were using a ModuleScript, the error is just saying that it doesn't think it is, so I just want to be certain. But if you click on the `ConfigsLevelModule` in the Explorer, and check the Properties widget, you can check the ClassName property. It should explicitly be a ModuleScript object.

Comment: It says Script as ClassName

Comment: How do I transform to ModuleScript? As I said I'm new to Roblox and Lua.... So I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Just right click on ReplicatedStorage and insert a ModuleScript, then copy and paste your existing code. Then delete the old Script and rename the new ModuleScript to `ConfigLevelsModule`